# Adding a foreign key to the model and a new model using codefirst migrations entity framework 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

This is my existing model.

```
public class Academy
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public int TeamId { get; set; }

        public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the new model.

```
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This is the migration script generated

```
namespace TestMigrations.Domain.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class teamNew : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Teams",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Name = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

            AddColumn("dbo.Academies", "TeamId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
            CreateIndex("dbo.Academies", "TeamId");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.Academies", "TeamId", "dbo.Teams", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Academies", "TeamId", "dbo.Teams");
            DropIndex("dbo.Academies", new[] { "TeamId" });
            DropColumn("dbo.Academies", "TeamId");
            DropTable("dbo.Teams");
        }
    }
}
```

There are existing records in academy, this is the error showing up:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.Academies_dbo.Teams_TeamId". The conflict occurred in database
>   "TestMigrations", table "dbo.Teams", column 'Id'.

I'm trying to figure out how to add a row on the Teams table so it can be referenced by the existing academy records. Or is there a much better way to deal with this error?

Comment: Make your `TeamId` nullable (on the Academies table)? If there's existing data in the table, then you might need to seed some teams and updated existing academy record, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is because you are configuring that one-to-many relationship  this way:

```
modelbuilder.Entity<Academy>()
            .HasRequired(a=>a.Team)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(a=>a.TeamId);
```

If you have configured your relationship this way, then the `Team` navigation property (or the `TeamID` FK property) *must be set* when you are going to save a new `Academy` in your DB. Due to you already have some academies in DB that don't have asociated a `Team`, EF is going to throw you that exception. Try configuring that relationship this way:

```
public class Academy
{
    //...
    public int? TeamId { get; set; }

    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in the `OnModelCreating` method on your context add this:

```
 modelbuilder.Entity<Academy>()
             .HasOptional(a=>a.Team)
             .WithMany()
             .HasForeignKey(a=>a.TeamId);
```